# removeView() on the child's parent first error on imageview

Tags: android

Am showing a image in a  ImageView.As on click of that imageview am showing alert dialog and showing the same image in bigger size,its working fine first time ,but second time when i click on that imageview am getting following error in my logcat,any help.

07-24 05:20:39.657: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Here is my code...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Button btn;
ImageView image1;
AlertDialog.Builder alert;
int imgvi=R.drawable.rose;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgfull);
    image1.setImageResource(imgvi);
    alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater=MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View layouti=inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview,null);
    alert.setView(layouti);
    final ImageView img=(ImageView) layouti.findViewById(R.id.imgfull);
    alert.setTitle("FullImage");
    img.setImageResource(imgvi);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    image1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        alert.show();   

        }
    });



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfull"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**imageview.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfull"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    ImageView image1;
    private int image = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgfull);
        image1.setImageResource(image);


        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              showImage(image);
            }
        });



    }

    public void showImage(int image){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.imageview, null);
        alert.setView(view);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgfull);
        alert.setTitle("FullImage");
        img.setImageResource(image);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alert.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you and can you please approve this ans so it may help others thanks....